# Wrap column name text in ggpairs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggpairs and while plotting the matrix, I receive a matrix as follows

[image]

As you can see, some of the text length is large and hence the text is not seen completely. Is there anyway that I can wrap the text so that it is visible completely.

Code

```
ggpairs(df)
```

I want the text to wrap so that it can be seen something like this

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `labeller` argument of `ggpairs` to pass a function to be applied to the facet strip text.

`ggplot` does have a nice ready function `label_wrap_gen()` that wrap the long labels.

By default `ggpairs` use the column names as labels, and those can't contain spaces. `label_wrap_gen()` need spaces to split the labels on multiple rows.

This is a solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
df <- iris

colnames(df) <- make.names(c('Long colname', 
                  'Quite long colname', 
                  'Longer tha usual colname',
                  'I\'m not even sure this should be a colname',
                  'The ever longest colname that one should be allowed to use'))

ggpairs(df, 
        columnLabels = gsub('.', ' ', colnames(df), fixed = T), 
        labeller = label_wrap_gen(10))
```

[image]